# PHP-CGI causing high CPU usage?

Tags: php, centos, cgi, fastcgi

I have been experiencing high CPU usage randomly and when it happens it will go from the regular CPU usage of 1%-2% all the way to 45%-60% CPU usage which is insane!

I am not sure what is causing this, but I detected it from connecting to the SSH of the server and typing `top` and then pressing `shift+p`.

**PICTURE OF WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE:** 
[image: x]

Is there anyway to fix this or anything as I am stuck. It doesn't happen all the time, it seems as if it's caused by 1 specific user accessing a file on the server and causing this massive loop. I'm not sure, can anyone help?

Comment: If you think its 1 user accessing a file, what file would that be and what would that file do? That may explain what the issue is

Comment: @Darren It would be api.php which all it does is sets/retrieves information from a mysql database. It doesn't make sense as the files mysql query's are optimized and working fine.

Comment: Hrm, and how costly are those queries if you don't mind me asking? It might not be the queries themselves, but the handling (*via php*)? The only way to find out where the issue is, is to test the various sections within api.php and troubleshoot your way to the cause!

Comment: @Darren It is being called every minute by my users. so mainly 1 request per 5 seconds.

Comment: @Darren I don't see how to test for it as it is totally random when it occurs and seems to only be from certain users. I heard it could be a loop that a user could be getting into from the php and keep's recalling it?

Comment: That could be possible yes, have you tracked it down to a specific user yet? If so, you could attempt to rate limit the calls to your API (*i.e. X calls per second*)

Comment: @Darren How would I limit the rate to all users? as they should only be calling it once per minute, unless they fail to call the php file then it will try again in 30 seconds.